# grub-install : command not found

Tags: grub

I had Windows 8.1 and Kali Linux installed in an extended partition. For some reason, I only formatted the partition where Windows was installed and re-installed. Now it only boot into Windows and doesn't show grub.

I'm using a live USB and tried to reinstall grub:

```
grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sda
```

and getting the error:

```
grub-install :command not found
```

Comment: try `sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sda`

grub-install is in your `/usr/sbin/` which is not in normal user's path.

Comment: I got `grub-install: command not found` because in CentOS 7, the command is grub2-install

Answer (score 8):

To add to the answer provided by user `@kirill-a` and flesh it out a bit more:

Here is what I did recently to restore the GRUB boot loader on a Windows 8 and Debian 8 dual-boot machine, after a Windows 8 reinstallation cleared the previous GRUB boot loader entry from the beginning of the disk.

**REPAIR GRUB2:  Live USB/CD 'chroot' method on linux:**

These instructions apply generally to an unencrypted, non-LVM disk on Debian-based distros, minor changes are needed in directory names and utilities used under RHEL/SUSE-based and possibly Arch-based distros.

Start with a bootable Live USB or CD of the distro of your choice.

1. Use `lsblk` to determine the kernel name descriptor (i.e. `/dev/xxyN`) of the block device with a missing or damaged GRUB boot loader.

All the following actions are to be done as root (use `su` or `sudo`).

2. Create a temporary mount point for the installed Linux:

   ```
   mkdir -p /mnt/linux
   ```

   (the `-p` option creates the parent directory `/mnt` if it doesn't already exist)
3. Using `/dev/xxyN` from previous `lsblk` command:

   ```
   mount /dev/xxyN /mnt/linux
   ```
4. The following command is only necessary if you have a separate `/boot` partition; `/dev/xxyN` here is representing the kernel name descriptor of your `/boot` partition.

   ```
   mount /dev/xxyN /mnt/linux/boot
   ```
5. Then:

   ```
   mount -t proc none /mnt/linux/proc
   mount -t sysfs sys /mnt/linux/sys
   mount -o bind /dev /mnt/linux/dev
   mount -t devpts pts /mnt/linux/dev/pts
   chroot /mnt/linux /bin/bash
   grep -v rootfs /proc/mounts > /etc/mtab
   grub-install /dev/xxy
   ```

   (Here, `dev/xxy` = the device name and number on which to install the GRUB boot loader , e.g., `/dev/sda`, not including the root partition number as in `/dev/sda1`)
6. If you wanted to make any other changes/customizations to GRUB, now is the time to edit the `/etc/default/grub` file, and save.

   ```
   grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
   ```
7. Reboot and verify.

Note: There are several additional steps to this procedure if your GRUB2 boot loader resides on a linux system with an LVM LV root and/or an encrypted root volume. Feel free to message me here, I have these additional instructions written down and have applied them successfully several times to an LVM LV on an ssd which contains a root volume encrypted with the kernel dm-crypt module.

Comment: This did not work for me until I logged in as root. I was using Debian 10 Buster live media

Comment: This is an old thread, but I found it useful. However, I had to mount /sys/firmware/efi/efivars to get grub-install to complete without the warning "EFI variables are not supported on this system."

Answer (score 3):

You need to `chroot` to your installed system and reinstall grub from there:

```
mount /dev/sda(number of partition with kali) /mnt
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
chroot /mnt bash
grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sda
update-grub
exit
reboot
```

Comment: update-grub

Generating grub.cfg ...
cat: /boot/grub/video.lst: No such file or directory
  No volume groups found
Found Windows 8 (loader) on /dev/sda1
done

Comment: it's not working .

Comment: try to reinstall grub or run the following command `echo vbe | sudo tee /boot/grub/video.lst` and update again.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is for `grub2-install` and `grub2-mkconfig` commands.

I was also getting `command not found` error on my Photon OS Linux box.

There were configuration files under `/boot/grub2`. So I was thinking that the grub2 package is already installed, but for some reason grub2-* commands are not working.

However, it turned out that grub2 package was not installed. Running below command fixed the issue.

```
yum install grub2 -y
```

For `grub-install` command, you will need to install `grub` package instead of `grub2`.