# grub booting problem

Tags: dual-boot, grub, kali-linux

I have Windows 8 and Kali Linux installed. While i was installing Kali there's an opportunity to install grub and i did it. But i am unable to boot Kali Linux and even see grub menu as far as there's the only boot option in boot menu i.e: windows boot manager so windows starts without grub. I tried to fix it by reinstalling and updating grub using post [grub-install : command not found](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183053/grub-install-command-not-found) instructions. Grub was successfully reinstalled and updated, recognized both windows and Kali(as there're listed in grub.cfg) but i can't fix booting problem.

Comment: you still not finding Kali in Grub menu?

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem on kali-win 10 dual boot.
The root of the problem seems to be Windows Boot Manager which excludes the grub EFI partition on your drive while booting.

Link to my question: [Kali Linux is Installed but not showing in boot manager](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/419773/kali-linux-is-installed-but-not-showing-in-boot-manager)

One Solution can be to install the os on Legacy Boot option.