# mount -o devpts pts /mnt/linux/dev/pts

Tags: grub

When I install kali linux found grub can't install. Then I'm using live USB tried to reinstall grub:

```
grub-install /dev/sda
```

I get this error:

```
grub-install: command not found
```

I am following [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183053/grub-install-command-not-found) until

```
5) mount -o devpts pts /mnt/linux/dev/pts
```

It gets this error:

```
mount: special device pts does not exist
```

What should I do?

Comment: @peterh,you can't understand,because the answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183053/grub-install-command-not-found has been modified.Can you understand me now? My problem had been solved.Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelSmith Now I can understand, I decoded and fixed it :-) Good luck for the answer, happy linuxing in the future! (Btw, if an answer solves your problem, you can accept it by clicking the pipe icon to the left. It is a reward for the answerer and also shows, exactly which answer solved your problem.)

Comment: @I know,I want,but I'm new here,my reputation less than 15,so I can't vote to the good answer.I will compensate when my reputation more than 15.

Comment: @IporSircer what? Kali is *not* off topic here! Please don't misinform users.

Comment: @MichaelSmith sorry about that. Kali is absolutely on topic here. The only issue is that many people seem to think that Kali is a toy instead of a professional tool aimed at experts. So we get a lot of question from newbies installing Kali, something they really have no business to do.

Comment: @terdon That's nothing.Last year I successfully installed linux,Each installation can be successful,it' easy.But now I can't install kali linux several times,I use kali linux for a year  just as a newbies,kali linux is stable.

Comment: Uhm. Yes, it is stable. But ***it is not a normal Linux distribution and should not be used as one***. It is a tool for experts and if you have non-expert questions while using it, people are unlikely to be willing to help you. For the same reason that people will not be willing to help someone who decided to learn how to drive on a formula 1 car.

Comment: @terdon I understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems to be a typo in the answer. The command should look something like:

```
mount -t devpts pts /mnt/linux/dev/pts
```

`devpts` is a type, not an option.